# In "Orphans of the Sky", what does the society's treatment of women indicate about the society?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, orphans-of-the-sky

In Heinlein's *Orphans of the Sky*, the people on the Ship treat women as if they're not people. There are references to "naming" their women like dogs, they make deals with father and husband, and are, I believe , referred to as "wenches" at several points. There are no women in high positions. There's also this quote:

> He washed himself, and went thence to the compartments of his uncle, for whom he worked for his meals. His aunt glanced up as he came in, but said nothing, as became a woman.

These seem to reflect negatively on the society. However, the story was originally published in 1941. Women's rights in [the 1940s](https://www.theclassroom.com/feminism-during-1940s-14003.html) weren't the way they were today.

So, two closely related questions:

1. Was this intended to reflect badly on the society, or was it simply in line with the thoughts of his time?
2. Regardless of what the author thought, how *does* this change our perception of the society in the Ship?

Comment: Apart from the treatment of women, was the society on the ship portrayed as ideal, or as gone horribly wrong?

Comment: @user14111 - that's the thing, it's hard to tell. I don't know how much of what I'm reading is colored differently through 2019 lenses than it would through 1941 lenses.